# How to increase the JMeter heap size without modifying the jmeter.bat file?

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, heap-memory

I have multiple script with multiple heap requirement. So How I can handle it dynamically without changing the bat file?Is it possible to pass the heap size from user defines property file?Environment variable?Can you kindly suggest. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

It's in the [getting started](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) manual:

> The environment variable JVM_ARGS can be used to override JVM settings in the jmeter.bat script. For example:

```
set JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dpropname=propvalue"
jmeter -t test.jmx …
```

Comment: Hi, Just want to clear some doubt. Need to set JVM_ARGS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dpropname=propvalue in environment variable and  execute the script in non-gui form with jmeter.bat -n -t"script.jmx. is my understanding correct. thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, jmeter adds JVM_ARGS variable to execution

Comment: I have to execute many scripts with different heap size can you suggest how I can handle it dynamically? whether directly from command prompt?

Comment: You can use build tool as jenkins or just create your own scripts with parameters. But it's a different question

Answer (score 0):

```
update your jmeter.sh file as below
java -server $JVM_ARGS -jar `dirname $0`/ApacheJMeter.jar "$@"

your executable".sh"(which has all information about jmeter home, script name which needs to be executed) should be as follows----
#!/bin/sh
JVM_ARGS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
JMETER_HOME=/tui/endeca/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/jmeter/app/apache-jmeter-3.1/
export JVM_ARGS
export JAVA_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $JVM_ARGS
#export JMETER_HOME
$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t "/tui/endeca/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/Script/TH/script.jmx"

To see the updated heap use the below in JSR223 Sampler(Thanks to Dmitri for solution)
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
def runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()
def arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments()
for (argument in arguments) {
    println('Effective JVM argument: ' + argument)
}
```